# How to send sms and call from app?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, delegates, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

> I have situation where On clicking on app icon i have to send sms and
>   call to a 5 numbers....do we have any third party api's or we have
>   predefined classes in ios?

Comment: You can use `MFMessageComposeViewController ` to send a message. But you can only call on number at a time using the `tel:` scheme.

Answer (score 1):

regarding the second part of your question "predefined classes in ios"

you can open the device caller or messages app using a url:

```
func sms(to number: String) {
   guard let url = URL(string: "sms:" + number) else {
      return
   }

   UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
}

func call(_ number: String) {
   guard let url = URL(string: "tel://" + number) else {
      return
   }

   UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
}
```

example:

```
sms(to: "12345678901")
call("12345678901")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send same message to multiple user at same time using [MFMessageComposerView](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-send-sms-text-message/). You can use third party api to message like [Nexmo](https://www.nexmo.com/) and [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/).

You can do call once a time. Below is code for call:

```
NSString *phoneNumber = @"YOUR_CALL_NUMBER"; 
NSString *phoneURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@", phoneNumber];
NSURL *phoneURL = [NSURL URLWithString:phoneURLString];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:phoneURL];
```